# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted from ios application

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, django

I send first request on server for getting cookies:

```
NSString* request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",SERVER_ADDRESS1];
responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
NSURLRequest *urlrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:request]];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlrequest delegate:self];
```

after we are setting properties (cookies and crsf token):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[responseData setLength:0];

NSHTTPURLResponse *HTTPResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
NSDictionary *fields = [HTTPResponse allHeaderFields];
self.cookies = [fields valueForKey:@"Set-Cookie"];
if (self.cookies){
    NSString *crsf = [NSString stringWithString:[[self.cookies componentsSeparatedByString:@";"] objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *rescrsf = [NSString stringWithString:[[crsf componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1]];
    self.cookies_csrf = rescrsf;
}
```

}

after we are print response and send second request :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSString *dump = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"data: %@", dump);
self.namesArray = [dump componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
[connection release];
[dump release];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://servername/login/"];
NSString *postBodyStr = [SKUtils reqBodyCreateNewUsername:@"demo" password:@"123" check:@"1"];
NSData *postBody = [postBodyStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postBody length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:self.cookies forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
[request setValue:self.cookies_csrf forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFToken" ];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];
[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

}

This moment is very interest: responce after second request look like html page with 403 error:

```
  <h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
  <p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
```

What I do wrong?

PS. additional methods from SKUtils :

```
+ (NSString *)reqBodyCreateNewUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)pass check:(NSString *)ch  {
NSArray *keys   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username",@"password",@"mobile", nil];
NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:username, pass,ch, nil];
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];

return [SKUtils generateURLForActivity:nil hostName:NULL andParams:params];
}



+ (NSString *)generateURLForActivity:(NSString *)activityName hostName:(const char *)host andParams:(NSDictionary *)params {
NSMutableDictionary *fullParams = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:params] autorelease];


NSMutableString *urlStr = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];

if (host != NULL) {
    [urlStr appendFormat:@"%s", host];
}
if (activityName != nil) {
    [urlStr appendFormat:@"%@?", activityName];
}


NSArray *allKeys =  [fullParams allKeys];
for (int paramIndex = 0; paramIndex < [allKeys count]; paramIndex++) {
    NSString *curKey = [allKeys objectAtIndex:paramIndex];
    id obj = [fullParams objectForKey:curKey];
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        [urlStr appendFormat:@"%@=%@&", curKey, [SKUtils escapeString:[fullParams objectForKey:curKey] withEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }
    else {
        [urlStr appendFormat:@"%@=%@&", curKey, [fullParams objectForKey:curKey]];
    }
}


NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlStr];
    return result;
}


+ (NSString *)escapeString:(NSString *)string withEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
{
//  CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&’()*+,;=”)
NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)string,
                                                                       NULL, (CFStringRef)@";/?:@&=$+{}<>,",
                                                                       CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(encoding));
return [result autorelease];
}
```

Comment: the body of your post request, the actual data, must contain a field named `csrfmiddlewaretoken`, which value is the same as the `csrftoken` cookie's value

Comment: @andrean   i changed my method + (NSString *)reqBodyCreateNewUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)pass check:(NSString *)ch csrfmiddlewaretoken:(NSString *)csrfMToken {
    NSArray *keys   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username",@"password",@"mobile",@"csrfmiddlewaretoken", nil];
    NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:username, pass, ch, csrfMToken, nil];
   ........    but i still have this error

Comment: the cookie's key/name should be `csrftoken`, while the post data's key /name is `csrfmiddlewaretoken`, is that correct?

Comment: @andrean what must i put in csrftoken?  only csrftoken?

Comment: a request header named `Cookie` has the following content when inspecting from firebug's network tab: `csrftoken=L5G5zlsblY8TsyT8jmcKnAAZPtpADJKc;`
also, the post data has:
`csrfmiddlewaretoken: L5G5zlsblY8TsyT8jmcKnAAZPtpADJKc`

Comment: @andrean yes, its true.

Should i delete X-CSRFToken from http header?

Comment: well it's not necessarily bad, there is an alternative to the approach we took now using that X-CSRFToken header, described here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax , I wonder why that didn't work out..

Comment: You also need to put the `{{ csrf_token }}` in your template

Comment: @dan-klasson  in http header? there are contained : [request setValue:self.cookies_csrf forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFToken" ];

Comment: No. But never mind that because I see that your cookie is being set.

Answer (score 0):

I find solution!!
remove line

```
[request setValue:self.cookies_csrf forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRFToken" ];
```

and paste this line

```
[request setValue:SERVER_ADDRESS1 forHTTPHeaderField:@"Referer" ];
```

SERVER_ADDRESS1 - address from first request.